# Uninstall multiple files fro Ubuntu at one go which get istalled by mistake

Tags: 18.04, unity

I was playing with my Ubuntu 18.04 (which I shouldn't ideally). I mistakenly installed unity tweak tool and it brings a lot of junk. I want to get rid of all that junk. In my app tray, I am getting some weird icons -->

---

[image: Like here you can see the shutdown icon]

[image: And here you can see the logout and reboot]

I tried to run the command `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove unity-tweak-tool`, it did uninstall something but after restart icons were still present.

---

Now I checked the recently installed apps list and here it is:

```
$ grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log
2019-04-20 21:49:59 install libmng2:amd64 <none> 2.0.2-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:50:00 install libsignon-glib1:amd64 <none> 1.14+17.04.20161117-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:01 install libunity-gtk2-parser0:amd64 <none> 0.0.0+18.04.20171202-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:01 install libunity-gtk3-parser0:amd64 <none> 0.0.0+18.04.20171202-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:02 install libunity-misc4:amd64 <none> 4.0.5+14.04.20140115-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:03 install sgml-base:all <none> 1.29
2019-04-20 21:50:04 install unity-gtk-module-common:all <none> 0.0.0+18.04.20171202-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:05 install unity-gtk2-module:amd64 <none> 0.0.0+18.04.20171202-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:05 install unity-gtk3-module:amd64 <none> 0.0.0+18.04.20171202-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:06 install libunity-control-center1:amd64 <none> 15.04.0+18.04.20180216-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:07 install activity-log-manager:amd64 <none> 0.9.7-0ubuntu26
2019-04-20 21:50:08 install qtcore4-l10n:all <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:09 install libqtcore4:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:10 install libqt4-xml:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:10 install libqtdbus4:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:11 install qtchooser:amd64 <none> 64-ga1b6736-5
2019-04-20 21:50:12 install qdbus:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:12 install libqt4-dbus:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:13 install libqt4-network:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:14 install libqt4-script:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:14 install libqt4-sql:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:15 install libqt4-xmlpatterns:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:16 install libqt4-declarative:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:17 install libqtgui4:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:18 install libdbusmenu-qt2:amd64 <none> 0.9.3+16.04.20160218-1ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:18 install appmenu-qt:amd64 <none> 0.2.7+14.04.20140305-0ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:50:19 install libbamf3-2:amd64 <none> 0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:20 install bamfdaemon:amd64 <none> 0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:20 install libsigc++-2.0-0v5:amd64 <none> 2.10.0-2
2019-04-20 21:50:21 install libglibmm-2.4-1v5:amd64 <none> 2.56.0-1
2019-04-20 21:50:22 install compiz-core:amd64 <none> 1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:23 install libdecoration0:amd64 <none> 1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:23 install compiz-plugins-default:amd64 <none> 1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:24 install libcompizconfig0:amd64 <none> 1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:25 install metacity-common:all <none> 1:3.28.0-1ubuntu0.1
2019-04-20 21:50:26 install libmetacity1:amd64 <none> 1:3.28.0-1ubuntu0.1
2019-04-20 21:50:27 install compiz-gnome:amd64 <none> 1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:28 install compiz:all <none> 1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:28 install libgeoclue0:amd64 <none> 0.12.99-4ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:50:29 install libnm-util2:amd64 <none> 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1
2019-04-20 21:50:30 install libnm-glib4:amd64 <none> 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1
2019-04-20 21:50:30 install geoclue:amd64 <none> 0.12.99-4ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:50:31 install geoclue-ubuntu-geoip:amd64 <none> 1.0.2+18.04.20180223-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:32 install libaccounts-glib0:amd64 <none> 1.23+17.04.20161104-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:32 install gir1.2-accounts-1.0:amd64 <none> 1.23+17.04.20161104-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:33 install gir1.2-gdata-0.0:amd64 <none> 0.17.9-2
2019-04-20 21:50:33 install gir1.2-signon-1.0:amd64 <none> 1.14+17.04.20161117-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:34 install gnome-calculator:amd64 <none> 1:3.28.2-1~ubuntu18.04.1
2019-04-20 21:50:35 install gnome-screensaver:amd64 <none> 3.6.1-8ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:50:36 install libatkmm-1.6-1v5:amd64 <none> 2.24.2-3
2019-04-20 21:50:36 install libcairomm-1.0-1v5:amd64 <none> 1.12.2-3
2019-04-20 21:50:37 install libpangomm-1.4-1v5:amd64 <none> 2.40.1-4
2019-04-20 21:50:39 install libgtkmm-3.0-1v5:amd64 <none> 3.22.2-2
2019-04-20 21:50:39 install gnome-system-monitor:amd64 <none> 3.28.2-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:40 install libcolumbus1-common:all <none> 1.1.0+15.10.20150806-0ubuntu12
2019-04-20 21:50:41 install libcolumbus1v5:amd64 <none> 1.1.0+15.10.20150806-0ubuntu12
2019-04-20 21:50:41 install libdbusmenu-qt5-2:amd64 <none> 0.9.3+16.04.20160218-1ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:42 install libgsettings-qt1:amd64 <none> 0.1+17.10.20170824-2fakesync1build2
2019-04-20 21:50:43 install libqt5sql5:amd64 <none> 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:50:43 install libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 <none> 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:50:44 install hud:amd64 <none> 14.10+17.10.20170619-0ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:50:44 install indicator-common:all <none> 16.10.0+18.04.20180321.1-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:45 install indicator-application:amd64 <none> 12.10.1+18.04.20190308.1-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:46 install indicator-appmenu:amd64 <none> 15.02.0+16.10.20160927-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:50:46 install liburl-dispatcher1:amd64 <none> 0.1+17.04.20170328-0ubuntu4
2019-04-20 21:50:47 install indicator-datetime:amd64 <none> 15.10+17.10.20170829.2-0ubuntu4
2019-04-20 21:50:48 install libfcitx-utils0:amd64 <none> 1:4.2.9.6-1
2019-04-20 21:50:48 install libfcitx-gclient1:amd64 <none> 1:4.2.9.6-1
2019-04-20 21:50:49 install liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64 <none> 1.26.0-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:50 install indicator-keyboard:amd64 <none> 0.0.0+18.04.20180216-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:51 install indicator-messages:amd64 <none> 13.10.1+17.04.20170120-0ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:50:51 install indicator-power:amd64 <none> 12.10.6+17.10.20170829.1-0ubuntu4
2019-04-20 21:50:52 install indicator-session:amd64 <none> 17.3.20+17.10.20171006-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:53 install jayatana:amd64 <none> 2.7-0ubuntu5
2019-04-20 21:50:54 install libfcitx-config4:amd64 <none> 1:4.2.9.6-1
2019-04-20 21:50:54 install libframe6:amd64 <none> 2.5.0daily13.06.05+16.10.20160809-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:55 install libgeonames-common:all <none> 0.2+17.04.20170220-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:56 install libgeonames0:amd64 <none> 0.2+17.04.20170220-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:56 install libglewmx1.13:amd64 <none> 1.13.0-4ubuntu0.18.04.1
2019-04-20 21:50:57 install libgrail6:amd64 <none> 3.1.0+16.04.20160125-0ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:50:58 install libido3-0.1-0:amd64 <none> 13.10.0+17.04.20161028-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:50:58 install mysql-common:all 5.8+1.0.4 5.8+1.0.4
2019-04-20 21:50:59 install libmysqlclient20:amd64 <none> 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
2019-04-20 21:51:00 install libnm-gtk0:amd64 <none> 1.8.10-2ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:51:00 install libnux-4.0-common:all <none> 4.0.8+18.04.20180622.2-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:01 install libgeis1:amd64 <none> 2.2.17+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:51:02 install libnux-4.0-0:amd64 <none> 4.0.8+18.04.20180622.2-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:02 install libqt4-sql-mysql:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:03 install libtelepathy-glib0:amd64 <none> 0.24.1-2
2019-04-20 21:51:04 install libtimezonemap-data:all <none> 0.4.5
2019-04-20 21:51:05 install libtimezonemap1:amd64 <none> 0.4.5
2019-04-20 21:51:05 install unity-services:amd64 <none> 7.5.0+18.04.20180413-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:06 install unity-schemas:all <none> 7.5.0+18.04.20180413-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:06 install libunity-core-6.0-9:amd64 <none> 7.5.0+18.04.20180413-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:07 install libunity-settings-daemon1:amd64 <none> 15.04.1+18.04.20180413-0ubuntu1.2
2019-04-20 21:51:08 install libzeitgeist-1.0-1:amd64 <none> 0.3.18-1ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:08 install nux-tools:amd64 <none> 4.0.8+18.04.20180622.2-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:10 install policykit-1-gnome:amd64 <none> 0.105-6ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:51:11 install python3-blinker:all <none> 1.4+dfsg1-0.1
2019-04-20 21:51:11 install python3-bs4:all <none> 4.6.0-1
2019-04-20 21:51:12 install python3-feedparser:all <none> 5.2.1-1
2019-04-20 21:51:13 install python3-webencodings:all <none> 0.5-2
2019-04-20 21:51:13 install python3-html5lib:all <none> 0.999999999-1
2019-04-20 21:51:14 install python3-jwt:all <none> 1.5.3+ds1-1
2019-04-20 21:51:15 install python3-lxml:amd64 <none> 4.2.1-1ubuntu0.1
2019-04-20 21:51:15 install python3-oauthlib:all <none> 2.0.6-1
2019-04-20 21:51:16 install qt-at-spi:amd64 <none> 0.4.0-8
2019-04-20 21:51:17 install rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist:all <none> 3.4.2-4ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:17 install session-shortcuts:all <none> 1.3
2019-04-20 21:51:18 install ubuntu-touch-sounds:all <none> 15.08
2019-04-20 21:51:18 install unity-asset-pool:all <none> 0.8.24+17.10.20170507-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:19 install unity-settings-daemon:amd64 <none> 15.04.1+18.04.20180413-0ubuntu1.2
2019-04-20 21:51:20 install unity-greeter:amd64 <none> 18.04.0+18.04.20180314.1-0ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:51:21 install unity-scopes-master-default:all <none> 6.8.2+16.04.20160212.1-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:21 install unity-scope-home:amd64 <none> 6.8.2+16.04.20160212.1-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:22 install unity:amd64 <none> 7.5.0+18.04.20180413-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:24 install indicator-bluetooth:amd64 <none> 0.0.6+17.10.20170605-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:25 install indicator-sound:amd64 <none> 12.10.2+18.04.20180420.3-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:26 install unity-control-center:amd64 <none> 15.04.0+18.04.20180216-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:27 install unity-lens-applications:amd64 <none> 7.1.0+16.10.20160927-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:27 install unity-lens-files:amd64 <none> 7.1.0+17.10.20170605-0ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:51:28 install unity-lens-music:amd64 <none> 6.9.1+16.04-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:28 install unity-lens-photos:all <none> 1.0+17.10.20170605-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:29 install unity-lens-video:amd64 <none> 0.3.15+16.04.20160212.1-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:30 install unity-scopes-runner:all <none> 7.1.4+18.04.20180209.1-0ubuntu2
2019-04-20 21:51:30 install unity-scope-calculator:all <none> 0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:31 install unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks:all <none> 0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:31 install unity-scope-colourlovers:all <none> 0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:32 install unity-scope-devhelp:all <none> 0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:32 install unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks:all <none> 0.1+13.10.20130809.1-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:33 install unity-scope-manpages:all <none> 3.0+14.04.20140324-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:33 install unity-scope-openclipart:all <none> 0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:33 install unity-scope-texdoc:all <none> 0.1+14.04.20140328-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:34 install unity-scope-tomboy:all <none> 0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:34 install unity-scope-video-remote:amd64 <none> 0.3.15+16.04.20160212.1-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:35 install unity-scope-virtualbox:all <none> 0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:36 install unity-scope-yelp:all <none> 0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:36 install unity-scope-zotero:all <none> 0.1+13.10.20130723-0ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:37 install unity-session:all <none> 3.28.1-0ubuntu3
2019-04-20 21:51:37 install unity-tweak-tool:all <none> 0.0.7ubuntu4
2019-04-20 21:51:38 install zeitgeist-datahub:amd64 <none> 1.0-0.1ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:39 install libgtk3-nocsd0:amd64 <none> 3-1ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:39 install gtk3-nocsd:all <none> 3-1ubuntu1
2019-04-20 21:51:40 install indicator-printers:amd64 <none> 0.1.7+17.10.20171101-0ubuntu1
```

I want to uninstall all those apps installed on that date.

Comment: grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log  I used this command to get that list

Comment: @user535733 I wish to learn until this is not a big problem. But if this is a big problem I would like to get rid of this asap.

Answer (score 0):

In general, once you've uninstalled a package,

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

will uninstall the packages it brought with it, if they're not needed by other packages.

Comment: Didn't work. Isn't there is any method to all those packages and uninstall in one go?